React custom hooks call inside function
const fun = () => { const result = useCustomHook() console.log(result) }
const useCustomHook = () => { const res = useNestCustomHook() console.log(res) }
dealing with custom hooks in React, where useCustomHook depends on another custom hook called useNestCustomHook. want to be able to call the fun function and have it return the result of useCustomHook, which should include the result of useNestCustomHook.

Yes, rename fun to useFun and call like any other React hook.

You cannot call hooks in general (custom also) outside of a react component or another custom hook. So your fun should be a react component.
const useCustomHook = () => { 
    const res = useNestCustomHook(); 
    console.log(res);
    return res; 
}

const Fun = () => { 
    const result = useCustomHook();
    console.log(result);
    return result;
}

Now you can use <Fun/> and render your result on browser.
You can find the react doc here
